# Problems with Grub 2 booting priority

Tags: bootloader, grub2

Right now I have this setup:

`/dev/sda1` is NTFS where I store my cross-platform accessible pictures/videos/etc.
`/dev/sda2` is my Windows 7 boot partition

`/dev/sdb1` is ext4 partition with Ubuntu 11.04 mounted at /
`/dev/sdb2` is my swap partition
`/dev/sdb3` is my /home partition

Problem is, when I boot, Grub (I think it's grub, at least) wants to automatically boot from /dev/sda1 but freaks out when it senses NTFS so it sends me to grub rescue mode where I follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Command%20Line%20and%20Rescue%20Mode) guide and get it to boot from `/dev/sdb1`.

I've set my BIOS boot order preference to prefer hd1 over hd0, but that doesn't help. I've also run `sudo update-grub` to see if I just needed to update grub after making all these new partitions and such.

Any ideas how to remedy this? I'd love even a grub menu over immediately booting into grub rescue mode.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom Menu in Grub2.  The guide for this can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 under 7. Custom Menu Entries.  You can add '#Custom Menu Entries' after the link I gave you to get to the correct place on the page.

A sample entry might look like: 
`menuentry "My Default Karmic" {` 
`set root=(hd0,1)` 
`search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set cb201140-52f8-4449-9a95-749b27b58ce8` 
`linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31-11-generic root=/dev/sdb1 ro quiet splash` 
`initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.31-11-generic` 
`}`

After you've made and tested your custom menu, you can make it the default choice by editing the GRUB_DEFAULT option in /etc/default/grub.